# django postgresql timestamp on entry creation is not ordered in the database

Tags: django, postgresql

I am quite new to django and I have a small app, with the following models:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class SomeModel(TimeStampedModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    some_json = JSONField(blank=True,default=dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid
```

I now make some requests to a webserver and write the return value of the  request to the database via model forms like so:

```
    data = requests.get(BASE_URL)
    form_data=collections.OrderedDict()

    form_data[  "some_json"   ] = data.json()
    form = SomeModel (form_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        logger.debug( "***** GOOD: form saved from %s", data.json() )
    else:
        logger.debug("**   form not valid because: %s ", form.errors)
    pass
```

It seems to work fine, but when I inspect the database I see that the timestemps are not ordered :( So, the top 5 entries on the database look like so (for the `created_at` field):

```
2020-08-17 19:59:14.377394+01
2020-08-17 19:58:31.017813+01
2020-08-17 20:00:33.302018+01
2020-08-17 19:59:57.626536+01
2020-08-17 19:59:07.671274+01
```

I am baffled as to how the database can write in non-ascending time stamps.. Am I missing something here? Shouldnt the database contain ordered values for the `created_at` field? My naive thinking leads me to think:
[1] I make the rerquest and get data
[2] write data to database
this process should create database entries in ascending order - no?

Since I use a logger, I can see that the values are fetched in acending order but it is not the case on the database.

Comment: The record can be rtrieved in any order possible, so not per se in the inseration order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem pleased see my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the database contain ordered values for the `created_at` field.

**No**. If you do not specify how to order the records, it can return records in any possible order. You can retrieve objects in an ordered order by using [**`.order_by(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
SomeModel.objects.order_by('created_at')
```

You can also specify a default ordering that is used if you do not specify one yourself by specifing an [**`ordering`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering):

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['created_at']
```

Comment: hmm but, I am looking directly at the database and the order at which it is inserted does not coincide with the ascending timestamp. Does my comment make sense? So, I am not taking of what values Django returns, I am talking about the inserted order in the database itself..

Comment: @AJW: but how do you determine the insert order. As said the top 5, etc. does not per se returns it in insert order.

Comment: I am determining the insert order by directly looking at the entires of the database via pgadmin4. I think the issue is with how pgadmin4 displays the data.. When I look at pgadmin, it looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/JmQAqAh.png I now realise that the number 1,2,3 do not really mean the order of insertion i.e they are not auto PKIDs.. Think I got myself confused here!

Comment: @AJW: if you make a model with an `AutoField` as primary key, you can take a look if the order is now correct, although I would think it is. No database frontend (including pgAdmin) can guarantee insertion order, since pgAdmin behind the curtains just makes queries like Django/... does.